# MIPS assembly on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2013, mips

I am looking for a way to program for MIPS assembly using VS2013 - but there is no assembly type project. 
Is there a way to do this and get the .s output files of MIPS so I can later run them on other machines, and if I can't do this on VS2013 than how do I program MIPS on Windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254312%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: What assembler are you planning on using? Visual Studio 2013 doesn't include a MIPS assembler. You have to go back Visual Studio 2008 to get one that includes a MIPS compiler (and I assume an assembler). You also need the Professional edition, it's not included with the free Express edition.

Answer (score 1):

The assembler used in visual studio is Microsoft assembler (MASM), and yes you can program assembly language on it.

select an "Empty Project" then configure the "Build Customizations" of the project to use MASM, *after* that add a new c++ source file and rename it to any name **.asm**

Here are the detailed steps:

http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2013/index.htm

And as for assembling your code to run on **MIPS,** **I guess you can't** do that with MASM, because it's a x86 assembler,
here is a list of the supported processor types directives on masm

> .386
>   .386P
>   .387
>   .486
>   .486P
>   .586
>   .586P
>   .686
>   .686P
>   .K3D
>   .MMX
>   .XMM

Refer to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8t163bt0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
the processor section.

Nevertheless,  there is an option in the project "Properties" > "Linker" > "advanced" that let you chose between different machines, including Mips, but I guess this will merely set the Machine Flag in the PE header to MIPS and when the assembler try to build your module it will find a conflict between the machine type flag and the code in the module. *But I'm not sure If you can build codes for MIPS.*

Answer (score 1):

To run MIPS programs on Windows 7, you need some type of emulator and a corresponding tool set. In the case of ARM processors, there are emulators that include a source level debugger and tool sets, including compilers, assemblers, linkers, and binary image output utilities for embedded systems. There's also a debugger for embedded systems that is run from Windows and some type of connection to the embedded system. The tool set runs on Windows, but targets the emulator or an actual embedded system. I don't know if there's a equivalent tool set and emulator like this for the MIPS processor.